# Nilpotent orbits in representations of exceptional groups

Tags: rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups, invariant-theory

The first nontrivial irreducible representation of $G_2$ is of 7-dimensional, and the first nontrivial representation of $F_4$ is of 26-dimensional.

My question is: how much is known about the nilpotent orbits in these representations? Any classification? or the answer is very easy,  there are only nilpotent orbits,  one is zero and another is nonzero orbit.

Comment: What do you mean by a nilpotent orbit of a representation that isn't the adjoint representation?

Comment: I think, we can define an orbit to be nilpotent if the closure contains zero

Comment: Can you be more specific?  If you are not using complex coefficients, then you need to specify which real form you are working with, since the answer will depend on this. For example, over the complex numbers, $G_2$ preserves a nondegenerate quadratic form (unique up to multiples) on $\mathbb{C}^7$. The nonzero null vectors of this quadratic form are a single $\mathrm{G}_2^\mathbb{C}$-orbit whose closure is the origin. For the split form of $\mathrm{G}_2$ acting on $\mathbb{R}^7$, the answer is the same. For the compact form of $\mathrm{G}_2$ acting on $\mathbb{R}^7$ all the orbits are closed.

Comment: @RobertBryant, I only work with complex numbers. Why in the case of G_2, there are only two nilpotent orbits? Any reference?  In fact, in the case of F_4, there is also a non-degenerate quadratic form on 26-dimensional representation. Is there similar result in this case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per the OP's comment, we are to assume that $\mathrm{G}_2$ and $\mathrm{F}_4$ mean the complex simple Lie groups.

Let's start with $\mathrm{G}_2\subset\mathrm{SO}(7,\mathbb{C})$, in its standard representation on $\mathbb{C}^7$, which is the vector space $V= \mathrm{Im}(\mathbb{O}^\mathbb{C})\subset \mathbb{O}^\mathbb{C}$, where $\mathbb{O}^\mathbb{C}$ is the (non-associative) algebra of octonions over the ground field $\mathbb{C}$.  Let $\mathbf{1}\in\mathbb{O}^\mathbb{C}$ be the multiplicative unit, and let $\langle,\rangle$ be the non-degenerate inner product on $\mathbb{O}^\mathbb{C}$ that satisfies $\langle xy, xy\rangle =  \langle x, x\rangle \langle y, y\rangle$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{O}^\mathbb{C}$.  Then $V = \mathbf{1}^\perp$, and, for $x\in V$, we have $x^2 = -\langle x,x\rangle\,\mathbf{1}$, and $\mathrm{G}_2$ is the group of automorphisms of $\mathbb{O}^\mathbb{C}$.  It is well-known that $\mathrm{G}_2$ acts simply transitively on the orthonormal triples $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ in $V$ that satisfy $\langle x_1x_2,x_3\rangle = 0$.

Since $\mathrm{G}_2$ preserves the non-degenerate quadratic form $\langle,\rangle$ on $\mathbb{C}^7$, each orbit of $\mathrm{G}_2$ lies in a level set of the non-degenerate quadratic form.

First, each level set $\langle x,x\rangle = \lambda \not=0$ is a single $\mathrm{G}_2$ orbit, as this follows from the fact that $\langle x,x\rangle = 1$ is a single $\mathrm{G}_2$-orbit, which, in turn follows from the above well-known characterization of $\mathrm{G}_2$.

Second, $\mathrm{G}_2$ fixes $0\in V$, so it only remains to understand the orbit structure on the level set $\langle x,x\rangle =0$ minus the origin.  Suppose that $x\not=0$ satisfies $\langle x,x\rangle =0$.  Then $x$ lies in a non-degenerate $2$-plane $E\subset V$ with an orthonormal basis $(x_1,x_2)$.  Select an element $x_3\in V$ of unit norm and perpendicular to $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_1x_2$, and let $F$ be the span of $x_1$, $x_2, x_3$.  From the above well-known result, $\mathrm{G}_2$ contains a subgroup $H$ that preserves $F$ and acts as $\mathrm{O}(3,\mathbb{C})$ on $F$.  Since $\mathrm{O}(3,\mathbb{C})$ acts transitively on the nonzero null elements in $\mathbb{C}^3$, it follows that $H$ acts transitively on the nonzero null vectors in $F$.
In particular, we can assume, after an action by an element of $H$, that $x = x_1 + i x_2$, and so, again, by the well-known result, we see that $\mathrm{G}_2$ must act transitively on the level set $\langle x,x\rangle =0$ minus the origin.

Hence $\mathrm{G}_2$ has exactly one non-closed orbit, i.e., the level set $\langle x,x\rangle =0$ minus the origin, and its closure is the level set $\langle x,x\rangle =0$.

The $\mathrm{F}_4$ case is a little more involved, and there are more non-closed orbits in its $26$-dimensional representation, but it can be understood in a similar way by identifying its representation of dimension $26$ as $\mathbb{J}_0$, the elements of the complex, $27$-dimensional exceptional Jordan algebra $\mathbb{J}$ that have zero trace, by using the structure of the Jordan algebra.  The key point is that $\mathrm{F}_4$ preserves both a quadratic and a cubic form on $\mathbb{J}_0$ and the non-closed orbits all lie the simultaneous zero set of those two forms.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Jordan algebra.  Could you please elaborate a bit more in the case of F_4?  For example, how many non-closed orbits?

Comment: @JJH:  I don't have time right now to put in a discussion of the $\mathrm{F}_4$ case.  In any case, I think it's probably in the literature somewhere.  I haven't worked out the details in a long time, but I believe that the answer is that there are two non-closed orbits in $\mathbb{J}_0\simeq\mathbb{C}^{26}$.  The larger non-closed orbit (which has dimension 24) is the set of those elements $X\in \mathbb{J}_0$ that satisfy $X^3 = 0$ but $X^2\not=0$.  The smaller orbit (which has dimension 16, I believe) is the set of those elements that satisfy $X^2 = 0$ but $X\not=0$.